# Missing Application Insights Telemetry on CodeLens after installing Resharper

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, resharper, azure-application-insights, codelens

I am having problems with CodeLens after installing R# and I would appreciate any help I could get.

After installing Resharper CodeLens stopped showing Telemetry, I should be seeing something like this:

[image]

Instead I get a broken Work Item list:

[image]

I tried uninstalling Resharper but it wont solve the problem, after reinstalling VS I got telemetry back but I installed Resharper again and the same thing happened.

Resharper is set to not disable CodeLens and all CodeLens options are enabled:

[image]
[image]

I have two accounts connected but Application Insights does not recognize my account for telemetry:

[image]

[image]

I have confirmed the problem on two other machines.

Versions:

VS: 15.6.3

R#: 2017.3.3

Comment: eric got your version #'s and will check it out.  Aside: i'd *uncheck* any codelens indicators you don't actively use.  not only does it prevent some of them from doing work you dont need, it also frees up keyboard shortcuts for the others, since they are ALT+0 - ALT+9 (not sure VS has extended that to more than 9), and the shortcuts are assigned in the order they show in that list and are enabled, so that the same shortcut always applies to the same indicator

Comment: is "team coding" a resharper one?  maybe try disabling that one and see if things start working again?

Comment: After last night update (15.6.4) team coding does not show as an option,  IntelliTrace seems to have replaced it.
I tried to leave all disabled and only enabled the App Insights options but it still does not work.

Comment: does it only happen the first time you open the first solution after opening VS?  we've found a case where now that our package has been converted to a VS "async" package, we get loaded AFTER the solution is loaded and don't get told that, so the extension doesn't know a solution is loaded and doesn't try to do anything with codelens.

Comment: Yes, I believe you perfectly isolated the issue, if I open another solution (or the same solution), close the solution but not VS and open the solution again all work as expected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a problem in the loading of the solution, as noted in the comments by VS team, a simple workaround is to close the solution (but not VS) and open again.